# C# how to send a message from one form to other just before close the form?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a program where I want it to ask a confirmation before close. It's just a simple form with the question and a `yes` and a `no` buttons. How can I send the information of which button was clicked back to the main form? All solutions I found were for communication with both forms opened, but when choosing a button in the second for it will close. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: On the close event, set a property on the main form.

Comment: Would Javascript confirmation popup boxes be enough ?
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: Sory, I'm new at C#. Your simple sentence means nothing to me.

Comment: I don't know hot to use Javascript in C# and my program is in Portuguese, so it would be better to have buttons with options in Portuguese, not English. But a "Comfirm Box" would be enough if it was in Portuguese and I knew how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second type of form you described is similar to the `MessageBox`… You can use its direct implementation as a dialog. Untested Example :

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure?",
    "Confirm Exit?",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if (dr==DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // Do work If Yes
}else //if( dr == DialogResult.No)
{
    // Do work if No
}
```

[See MSDN for `MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I think it's solves my problem. I didn't know the message box had a "yes or no" option. I will try it when I can, I will pick the program again just tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do it this way.

Code for child form:

```
        private bool _bDoSomething=false;

        public bool showForm()
        {
            this.ShowDialog();
            return _bDoSomething;
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _bDoSomething=true;
            this.Hide();
        }
```

And then this sort of code for the parent form:

```
        dlgMyForm dlgMyForm = new dlgMyForm();
        if (dlgMyForm.showForm())
        {
          //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean value in main form as public

```
 public Boolean check =false;
```

In the second form's FormClosing event do the following

```
 private void Form2_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
   DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("[Your text]",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

   if(answer == DialogResult.Yes)
     {

       Form1.check=True; //if button yes is clicked 
                         // set the form1 check variable to True and closes form2

     }
   else
     {
          Form1.check=False; //if button no is clicked 
                           // set the form1 check variable to False and cancel form 
                           // closing                                  
          e.Cancel=True;
     }


}
```

Use the boolean variable check  to do further processing in form1